# params T[] vs IEnumerable<T> as parameter type

Tags: c#, api, api-design

I know there's a [proposal for `params IEnumerable<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/179).

When designing an API, when should we choose `params T[]` (params array) over `IEnumerable<T>`. Or should both be implemented for better end-user experience?

Example:

`void MyCoolMethod(params string[] strings)`

`void MyCoolMethod(IEnumerable<string> strings)`

When using `params` invocation is greatly simplified, but then if you want to pass some `IEnumerable` then you have to call `ToArray`.

Answer (score 6):

The `params` keyword is only useful, when you as the coder will pass a number of strings that can vary between calls and you don't want to put them into an array manually for every call.

The `IEnumerable<T>` data type is useful, when you as a coder have a collection of any type and want to pass it.

So tailor your method to your audience. Those string you pass, do they come as hardcoded string from the developer? Like `.Allow("GET", "PUT", "POST")` or do they come from a different routine in your program like `.Allow(this.ReadAllowedVerbsFromConfiguration())`?

When the human sitting in front of the machine has to type out the parameters, use `params`, otherwise an `IEnumerable<T>` might be the better choice.

Comment: I think both situations are possible.

Comment: @Konrad then have an overload that passes one to the other

Comment: How the input is to be expressed will determine how easy it is to use this function. So find out what makes for easy usage. Implement function signatures that are sensible and support that usage.